# FTP from unix to windows from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ftp

Hi i know there are similar questions out there but i still have some doubt as i am new to this.I want to FTP my file(abc.txt) from **UNiX** box to **windows** box.I tried one script as given below.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='my window ip address?'
USER='unix user?'
PASSWD='unix password?'
FILE='/opt/sie/w44gq8as/abc.txt'
ftp $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
user $USER
$PASSWD
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
exit 0
```

My doubts are already in my script i want to know few questions .

**HOST**-: Is this windows ip address i want to ftp?

**User**: Is this unix user or window user?

**Password** : unix server pass or window ?

Is above script ok for FTP from unix to windows? Sorry if i am asking something really silly but i am somewhat confused.

Comment: Your script seems to be a close copy of the script labelled as "non-working" at http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html -- the same page shows you a working script. Also, read the bash docs about *here documents*, since that's what's being used here.

Comment: We don't care about Unix user or Windows user in your context. There are just FTP user. So use FTP server address, FTP user and FTP user' password.

Comment: @slim i am currently on office network so can not open that link i will check that at home .

Comment: @Dorian seems to be a good point .

Comment: BTW driving `/usr/bin/ftp` from a shell script is pretty fragile and inflexible. I strongly suggest using an ftp client library in your favourite "proper" scripting language - python/ruby/groovy/perl/whatever so you have more control and can handle errors properly.

Answer (score 0):

All the information will be relating to the server you are trying to connect to and so in your case the Windows server. So the Windows IP address, the Windows username and the Windows password

Comment: User and Password of the Windows' FTP server, not necessarily the same of the Windows OS

Comment: As Bozzy pointed out. I wasn't clear, the ftp service on the Windows machine will have ftp accounts set up associated with the ftp service. You will need the username and password relating to one of these accounts.